# Google app script - search hosted attachments

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

How to search for hosted attachments in google sites using Google App script?
 I tried to search using `page.search("query", options)` with page type as `Webpage`, `Filecabinetpage`, but I'm not able to search my page attachments.
Can anybody help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct search method. However, you can use the [`Page.getAttachments()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/page#getAttachments%28%29) to get a list of attachments and do a manual search through them.

You can open a request in the Issue tracker for this feature to be added.

Comment: Thanks Srik, I have one more question, if the same is possible with FileCabinetPage .Like, search FileCabinetPage using filenames.